# JList stop selecting last item

Tags: java, swing, select, jlist

I have problem with JList selecting. When I click on any of objects in JList, it will be selected (that is fine).

But when I click below all of objects (on blank place) the last item in JList will be selected.
How can I turn it off? I do not want to select last object in JList after clicking below all of objects (on blank space).

After few comments I am adding here sample of code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class TestOfJList extends JFrame{

private static JList playList;
private static DefaultListModel<String> modelPlayList;  
private static JPanel mainPanel;
private static MyCellRenderer myRendererForJlist;

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    try {       
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JListTest!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(700, 250, 300, 400);       
    frame.setResizable(false);    

    mainPanel = new JPanel();

    modelPlayList = new DefaultListModel<String>();

    modelPlayList.addElement("Hello world!");
    modelPlayList.addElement("Hello heaven!");
    modelPlayList.addElement("Hello hell!");


    playList = new JList(modelPlayList);

    playList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270,500));
    playList.setVisible(true);
    playList.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);       
    playList.setSelectionBackground(Color.YELLOW);      
    playList.setSelectedIndex(0);
    playList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    playList.setDragEnabled(true);      
    playList.setDropMode(javax.swing.DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);
    playList.setFixedCellHeight(20);        

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(playList);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));

    mainPanel.add(scrollPane);

    myRendererForJlist = new MyCellRenderer();      
    playList.setCellRenderer(myRendererForJlist);

    frame.add(mainPanel);       
    frame.setVisible(true);     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

---

MCVE 2:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestList {
   public static final String[] ITEMS = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JList<String> myList = new JList<>(ITEMS);
            myList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
            JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane(myList);

            // just to see what listeners are involved
            MouseListener[] mouseListeners = myList.getListeners(MouseListener.class);
            System.out.println(mouseListeners.length);

            MouseMotionListener[] mouseMotionListeners = myList.getListeners(MouseMotionListener.class);
            System.out.println(mouseMotionListeners.length);


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sPane);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code, how you are constructing this list

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Code was added. I think it can be open now.

Comment: One problem that I see is your setting sizes and/or preferred sizes so that your JList is larger than it should be. You should never be setting sizes or preferred sizes on a JList.

Comment: That still don't solve my problem. When I comment these lines it still select the last object after clicking below all of objects.
Size/prefferedsize have nothing to do with that.

Comment: Agree, that does not solve the problem, and I frankly don't yet know the solution. I have added a much simpler MCVE program to your question, since it looks like most of the code in your original is not necessary for demonstrating the problem. You can keep or delete my MCVE as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change preferred size of scrollpane because it expands over complete mainpanel and when you click below last element(in empty space ) it gets selected

Change :-

```
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
```

to

```
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
```

Now click below list will not change selection.

It will be visible as below
[image]

Comment: I did what you said and it still dont work. After i click below all objects in JList, the last element is selected.

Comment: you need to set preferred size in such a way that user will not be able to click in emtpy area of scrollpane. See the differnce in color of scrollpane(dark grey) and panel(light)

Comment: scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,70));

Comment: Thats not correct solution for this, because I dont know how much objects will be in JList. If I use your solution I will have to still check how much objects are in JList and with this in mind I have to change size of JList. Thats alot of work to do. There have to be another better solution like this.

Comment: Thats where jscrollpane will come into picture . Add 10-11 elements and check

Comment: Yeah when I will have full JList then will come jscrollPane. But look at this. When I will have 1 object in JList then JList have to be 20 pixel height.
2 objects = 40 pixel height
3 objects = 60 pixel height
...
Until JList will be not around 400 pixel height, then will come jscrollPane.
And with your solution I have to everytime check if JList is 400 pixel height and if is not then I have to make him by 20 pixel bigger.

Comment: Just an idea not sure if it will help or not.
change lines in  MCVE2 with this.
myList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
                JPanel jp=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
                jp.add(myList);
                JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane(jp);